# How to create a type in TypeScript which can be a class or a function?

Tags: typescript

I thought this could be accomplished like this:

```
abstract class Stuff() {
}
class Foox extends Stuff {
    constructor() {

    }
}
type Func = {
    (a: number): number
}

let y: Func | Stuff;

y = (a = 1) => { return a }
y = Foox;

new y(); // doesn't work. This expression is not constructable. Type 'Foox' has no construct signatures
```

This works:

```
y = (a: 1) => { return a }
y = new Foox();
```

but this is not what I want. I want to create a value which is either a function with a specific signature or a class, *not* the instance of the class. How can I do this?

EDIT:

Sorry, my question wasn't entirely precise.
This is what I need:

```
abstract class Stuff {
}
class Foox extends Stuff {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
type Func = {
    (a: number): number
}

let y: Func | Foox;

y = (a = 1) => { return a }
y = Foox;

new y(); // doesn't work. This expression is not constructable. Type 'Foox' has no construct signatures
```

So even this doesn't work. But I don't even know the name of the subclass. All I know if that it extends the abstract class Stuff. And I would like to create type:

Function | subclass of Stuff.

EDIT 2:

Managed to make it work thanks for the suggestions guys!

```
let y: Func | typeof Stuff;
```

works. Well, kinda. I'm still getting a warning, but it's OK.

And the code that checks which type it is is just:

```
if(y instanceof Stuff.prototype) {
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures)?

Comment: OK thanks this works, however my question wasn't entirely correct. Problem is Foox is an abstract class. So what I really want is: let y: Func | subclass of Foox. I'm gonna edit the question to clarify

Comment: If you don't know whether `y` is a function or a class, how do you know whether you should call it like `y()` or `new y()`?

Comment: We know that because when y gets passed (by an event handler) we can test if y === ClassName or something like that. If it's not equal, then it's a function

Comment: Or we can test if y has a constructor, if it then it's the class. etc.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpg2gN) work for you? Test it against your use cases; if it doesn't work, please [edit] the example code to show how (e.g., show code that tests the value to see if it should call or `new` it).  If it does work I can maybe write up an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Actually, it doesn't, but managed to make it work with typeof Foo (without the new).